# How to convert this oracle query to typeorm?

Tags: oracle, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I was building an application in NestJS and I need to get the date from the Oracle, but I don't know how convert this query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;
```

In a TypeORM query.

Can you help me?

Comment: The date must come from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this way to get what I wanted:

```
await getManager().query(`SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW" FROM DUAL`);
```